# Directory structure variations in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script `myautoappupgrade.sh` where I automate a process of application upgrade. The script has to be run on few different servers. Unfortunately, the application is located in slightly different directory on each server - the number for parent directory varies between 1-20. How I can modify the script, so that the directory can be replaced by some sort of variable? I don't want to edit the script for each server because there are many directory queries in the automation script.

example:

```
cd /ae1/apps/myapp/upgradefiles/
unzip file.zip
./install.sh
```

the directory slightly changes on another server:

```
cd /ae2/apps/myapp/upgradefiles/
unzip file.zip
./install.sh
```

and another..

```
cd /ae3/apps/myapp/upgradefiles/
unzip file.zip
./install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$1
cd /ae${num}/apps/myapp/upgradefiles/file.zip
unzip file.zip
./install.sh
```

Then call the script with the number as first argument:

```
myautoappupgrade.sh 1
```

Comment: If it helped, you may mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and obvious solution is to not hard-code the directory at all.  Modify the script so it accepts the parent directory as an argument, or just `cd` into the parent directory before running the script.

Perhaps something like this:

```
while read server dir; do
    ssh "$server" "cd '$dir' && unzip apps/myapp/upgradefiles/file.zip/file.zip && ./install.sh"
done <<\:
   ernie          /ae1
   bert           /ae2
   cookiemonster  /home/cmonster/anN
:
```

It would probably be even better if you unzipped into a temporary directory, but hopefully this should get you moving in the right direction.

Of course, if you can be sure that `/ae[0-1]` is always there and there is only one match,

```
cd /ae[0-9]/apps/myapp/upgradefiles/file.zip
```

would do what you are asking.

(Do you *really* have a file named `file.zip` inside a directory also named `file.zip`? I'm guessing actually take away the `file.zip` from the end of the `cd` path.)

Answer (score 0):

By simply using:

```
cd /ae*/apps/myapp/upgradefiles/
```

The * will expand any character.